# when to generate pre-signed urls

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a tableview that fetches data from a postgres db on Heroku.  Each cell of the tableview represents an audio file that is stored on S3.  I use the `trackID` that is returned from postgres for each cell to access the audio file by creating a url like below:

```
 let audioURL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucketname>/<trackID>.m4a"
 self.player!.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
```

This will result in an error, since I don't have direct access to the S3 files.  I believe I'm going to need `pre-signed urls` from `boto3` to be able to make a `GET` request for the files.  Should I be generating the pre-signed urls when the file is selected for playing or should I obtain the pre-signed urls for each file when making my original fetch request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Pre-Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) is a way of providing temporary access to private objects that are stored in Amazon S3.

The pre-signed URL consists of:

- The file URL
- An **Access Key** associated with a user that has permissions to GET the file
- An expiration timestamp
- A hashed **signature** based on the authorised user's Secret Key (which is matched with their Access Key)

The pre-signed URL can be generated from a few lines of code and is only **evaluated** when the GET request is sent to Amazon S3.

When using Amazon S3 to fetch objects for a **web page**, the pre-signed URL should be generated server-side so that credentials are not sent to the client. Therefore, the pre-signed URL would be generated at the time that the HTML is generated.

However, it appears that you are coding for **iOS**. Therefore there are two potential scenarios:

- You could generate **temporary AWS credentials** using the [AWS Security Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html), with permission to access all relevant content in S3 for the duration of the credentials, or
- You could have the iOS app **make a request to the back-end for a file**, then the back-end checks whether the user is authorised to access the file and, if so, returns an Amazon S3 pre-signed URL to the file.

The first method reduces the load on the back-end server by permitting the iOS app to directly request content from Amazon S3. The second method provides the ability to check every file access before granting access, and has the benefit that you can easily log each request.

Comment: When the user uploads an audio file, they choose whether they want it to be public or private.  If a file is public, it will appear in the tableview for all users to access. The backend does all the work to determine which files appear in the tableview.  So for the second method you suggested, we don't need to determine if a user has access to a specific file - If a user can see it, then they have access.  I think this is the best way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-signed urls have an expiration time, which defaults to one hour in `boto3`. It is likely going to be better for you to generate them as the file is selected.